# A question about one step in the proof of $E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a continuous nonnegative random variable with cdf $F_X(x)$ and pdf $f_X(x)$. I don't understand how we obtain the third equality in the following proof:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We [change the order of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), noting the integration region is $0\le x\le y\le\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem.